# How to print a document, to create an invoice in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I've been looking around for ages, and not sure I'm finding the answer. I'm new to coding so apologies if this seems basic.
I'm attempting to produce a printed invoice, using various inputs within Windows Form. I've found that the current code is overwriting the previous line.
I've included the Print Preview, as this also shows as overwritten lines

```
    private void PrintPreviewControl()
    {
        Form previewForm = new Form();
    PrintPreviewControl previewControl = new PrintPreviewControl();

    previewControl.Document = printDocument1;
        previewControl.Zoom = 0.5;
        previewControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        previewForm.Controls.Add(previewControl);
        previewForm.ShowDialog();
        previewForm.Dispose();
    }
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

            Single vPos = 0; //y-axe
            Single hPos = 0; //x-axe

            //Font
            Font fontMedium = new Font("Arial", 16);
            Font fontLargeBold = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
            //Font myFont = new Font();

            //Brush
            Brush brushBlue = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
            Brush brushBlack = Brushes.Black;
            Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua);

        hPos = 100;
        vPos = 150;
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Name", fontLargeBold, brushBlue, hPos, vPos);
        hPos = 300;
        vPos = 150;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lbxTitle.Text, fontMedium, brushBlack, hPos, vPos);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtName.Text, fontMedium, brushBlack, hPos, vPos);
        hPos = 300;
        vPos = 150;

        hPos = 100;
        vPos = 200;
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Email", fontLargeBold, brushBlue, hPos, vPos);
        hPos = 100;
        vPos = 200;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtEmail.Text, fontMedium, brushBlack, hPos, vPos);
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use an RDLC report, which is included in Visual Studio and very powerful. It allows the user to print or export it to standard document types (e.g. pdf, Excel, Word).

Comment: Which lines are overwriting?  Do you ever print the data?  Is there more than one page?  The entire method is not shown

Comment: don't do this by hand...it looks easy now but youll regret it when something doesnt work and you spend a ton trying to fix something that the out of the box reports do automatically

Comment: Several shown positions are equal!

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by position? I'm guessing you mean the hPos and vPos. As I said I'm leaning this at college, and I've never really had any XP before. Is it that hPos and vPos relate to Horizontal and Vertical location? Probably answering own question, but checking :)